# "what are you in the mood of today" is it correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

"what are you in the mood of today"

is that a correct way of asking someone what they wanna do (moodwise)
i know " what do you feel like doing " is more common way but just wanna know whether the earliar mentioned way is also right or not

Comment: Any reason to think it is correct, or is there any reason for you to think it isn't correct? Why are you asking about this particular sentence today?

Comment: *What are you in the mood **for** today* = *What do you feel like doing?, What do you **want** to do?*. There's also the possibility of *What mood **are you in** today?* = *What is your current mood? (Are you sad, angry, etc.).*

Comment: so is this sentence correct " what are you in the mood for talking today"

Comment: so is this sentence correct " what are you in the mood for talking today"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "... in the mood **for**" is more idiomatic than "mood **of**". Apart from that, the sentence is correct.

Note, don't use "wanna" unless you are speaking, or indicating how something is spoken (such as in a song lyric). In writing the spelling is always "want to"

"What are you in the mood for?" asks the same as "What do you want to do?" 
On the other hand, "What mood are you in asks about your emotions.

You can't say "What are you in the mood for talking", because the verb "talk" is intransitive; it doesn't have a direct object; you don't say "I talk food" but you say "I talk about food", for example.  So you can say "What are in the mood for talking about today?", or you can say "What are you in the mood for discussing today". "Discuss" is a transitive verb.

Comment: Yes, but I'd say ***for*** is more than *slightly* more idiomatic. It's perfectly natural, whereas *to be in the mood **of** something* has no currency whatsoever, and never did.

Comment: so is this sentence correct " what are you in the mood for talking today"

Comment: Edited to extend answer.